# C++ static const string in header c++11

Tags: c++, string, c++11, entity, constants

I'm wanting to write a class that provides limited RTTI information.

Now what I want is something like this

```
template<typename T>
struct isGameComponent
{
   public:
   static_assert(false,"If a non-specialized version is created we have problems");
}

template<>
struct isGameComponent<Transform>
{
  public:
  static const char* COMPONENT_TYPE_NAME = "Transform";
  static const uint32_t COMPONENT_TYPE_ID = HashString("Transform"); //constexpr 
};

//Do this a lot more
```

I get a compile time error though saying I can't initialize the string as it is not a literal type. I was wanting to keep this lib header only. Is that impossible?

Comment: what's wrong with `typeid`

Comment: The eventual desire is to do this with some sort of scripting such that I create a scriptable component whose name can be hashed into an integer and I want this system to build into it. This is just a convenience template so I can build a Macro that does this in all my C++ based classes with minimal rewriting of code. typeid won't extend into non-c++ classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep the module as header only you have several options:

- `inline` functions that return the values.
- the templated constant trick.
- C++11 `constexpr` keyword.

---

Example of inline functions:

```
template<typename T>
struct IsGameComponent;

template<>
struct IsGameComponent<Transform>
{
    static
    auto componenTypeName()
        -> const char*
    { return "Transform"; }

    static
    auto componentTypeId()
        -> uint32_t
    {
        static uint32_t const theId = hashString("Transform");
        return the_id;
    }
};
```

---

Example of the templated constant trick:

```
template<typename T>
struct IsGameComponent;

template< class Dummy_ >
struct C_IsGameComponent_Transform
{
    static char const* const componentTypeName;
    static uint32_t const componentTypeId;
};

template< class D >
char const* const C_IsGameComponent_Transform<D>::componentTypeName = "Transform";

template< class D >
uint32_t const C_IsGameComponent_Transform<D>::componentTypeId  = hashString( "Transform" );

template<>
struct IsGameComponent<Transform>
    : C_IsGameComponent_Transform<void>
{
    // Constants available here.
};
```

---

Example of C++11 `constexpr` (this requires that `hashString` is a `constexpr` function):

```
template<typename T>
struct IsGameComponent;

template< class Dummy_ >
struct C_IsGameComponent_Transform
{
    static char const* constexpr componentTypeName = "Transform";
    static uint32_t constexpr componentTypeId = hashString( "Transform" );
};
```

With this solution you can't take the address of any of these constants.

---

Disclaimer: none of the code above has been near any C++ compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Define those static members out of the class declaration:

```
const char *isGameComponent<Transform>::COMPONENT_TYPE_NAME = "Transform";

const uint32_t isGameComponent<Transform>::COMPONENT_TYPE_ID = HashString("...");
```

If you put these definitions in the header file, then you will have multiple statics in every translation unit which may cause some issues. If you put them in a cpp file the you have one and it is recommended.

Comment: "If you put them in a cpp file the you have one and it is recommended." is incompatible with the requirement/wish for a header-only module.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Yes, I've just recommended it ;-)

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm doing. Thought you could declare static const values in the class though. Guess just only data types like integer and floating point base types work.